# Set the width of an element equal to monitor size WITHOUT varying on zoom

Tags: javascript, html, css

I would like to set the width of an element as a relationship of the native resolution of the viewer's monitor.

I understand that CSS "width:100%;" exists, but I am not happy with the way that method deforms layout, or may behave in a frustrating manner for viewers who want to zoom in/out.

Instead, I'd like to be able to have an element behave like "width:100%" only at zoom=100%. Is this possible (with CSS or Javascript)?

Comment: the css units `vw` and `vh` are viewport width and viewport height of users monitor that stay relative while zooming. You could use them instead of percentage. Be aware that `1vw` is 1% of users viewport width, so setting `100vw` means exactly as the users viewport width.

Comment: Whenever possible make sure your application can deal with resizing of the browser window. This includes supporting unexpected resolutions (3:4 (vertical) for instance, or 16:9 and 16:10), and live resizing of the viewport. If you can no longer render the application correctly opt for graceful degradation. For instance: add scrollbars when things get squashed too much, this doesn't look nice but your application remains usable. Use media queries and a responsive UI to support a wide range of viewports.

Comment: If you could post 2 images showing what you want and what you get, we would be more able to give some good answers

Answer (score 0):

vw and vh are the units which you need to use. viewport (monitor of the user) is measured using vw and vh. (viewport width and viewport height respectively.)

1vw = 1% of Viewport width

vh is the behaving same. 100vh is same as 100% of viewport height.

100vw and 100vh are same to the full monitor width and height.